# Android app: account is not allowed to suggest edits

Tags: bug, android-app

Official SEx app 1.0.35 (Android 4.2.1), posting on ServerFault. Can suggest edits via browser, cannot do the same through the app.

Comment: This looks like an API misfeature.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange apps doesn't support suggested edits (can't push edits in review queue) - only instant. But error doesn't tell it, they should change it to something like "App doesn't support suggested edits".