# Android app: Editing tags is not supported

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, android-app

According to this Q&A: [Android app should send edits to edit queue if necessary rather than rejecting them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208471/android-app-should-send-edits-to-edit-queue-if-necessary-rather-than-rejecting-t) there was a missing feature in the API, what hindered apps to push edits into the suggested edits queue. According to the same Q&A this feature was added in December 2014.

When will this feature be available in the StackExchange App?

Related Q&As:

- [Can't suggest edits on Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227030/cant-suggest-edits-on-android-app)
- [Android app: account is not allowed to suggest edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233649/android-app-account-is-not-allowed-to-suggest-edits)
- [Cannot edit posts on iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225138/cannot-edit-posts-on-ios-app)

Comment: From Kasra's comment: *"it will be in the next beta update"*. There's really no need for a separate question asking when a feature request will be implemented.